# UITextView font size is so small in iPad Mini but normal on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uitextview, ipad-mini

This is driving me crazy. I have an iPad Mini as my real test device. There's an `UITextView` and it's insanely small. I can not tell why the `UITextView` is all normal when opening the app on an emulator. I can't use my desired font size on any `UITextView` on iPad Mini.

Here's screen shot:

Small font size screenshot (real device - iPad Mini)

[image]

Normal desired font size (emulator - iPad Pro)

[image]

I don't know if anyone had faced this issue before. I couldn't find any related questions on this site nor Google. Any suggestions?

iPad Mini runs on iOS 9.3.5 and simulator runs on 11.4

Comment: Images are broken.

Comment: please share ios version you r testing on , also share sample code

Comment: @Mukesh I shared iOS versions. Also I don't have any code related to styling `UITextView`s

Comment: @Glenn images are fixed.

Comment: Are you using auto layout and/or dynamic text?

Comment: No I don't. It seems that when I uncheck Editable and Selectable, font size preferences go missing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it could be a setting problem on device

On your device 
Setting - General - Accessibility - Larger text 
If it’s smaller than average set it again!

Comment: I tried to reset all settings hoping that'd fix the issue but I still got nothing.

Comment: @Emre A is it custom font??

Comment: System font. Anyways, I checked Selectable and unchecked Editable and it seems works for now.